# Disable Mailman Reminders

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mailman

We run a mailserver on OSX server, and a few mailing lists. The password/subscription reminds USED to come out at 8AM (local), but in the past months it's moved to 5AM, a nuisance to all involved.

It would appear that mailman has been modified by Apple because there is no cronjob entry I can find that controls when these reminder notices come out, and I haven't found any launch agent/daemon plists that would control this ether. Nor have I found anything in the mailman configuration web pages.

So... where are they?! Due to the specific-announcement style of use, they're a fairly worthless message to be originated, and they are a huge bother when announcing to support phones.

Comment: Are they not in /usr/lib/cron/tabs/mailman? Or viewable via 'sudo crontab -u mailman -l' from Terminal?

Comment: For you own reference, sbr, it would be crontab -u _mailman -l. System users on OSX are prefixed with _.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable list reminders on a per-list basis.
The option is "send_reminders" and it's in the notifications section of the general options page. 
http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/mailman-admin/node13.html

The script sends the notifications is "mailpasswds". On a Debian system it's in /usr/lib/mailman/cron, but I do not have access to an OS X Server machine to find it for you.

OS X stores crontabs in /usr/lib/cron/tabs, it's worth checking here to see if mailpasswds is invoked.

Comment: Iiiiiiiiiiiii am blind. Holy crap, it's been sitting on that page all long. There is no good excuse for missing that option entirely. Even after reading this I couldn't find it for another ~3 minutes or so! Ugggh. Thank you. [edit] Blah, 5 more hours until I can award the bounty...

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will be enough to get you started:

[How do I use the Apple-provided version of Mailman under Mac OS X Server?](http://wiki.list.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4030530)

The general consensus seems to be that Apple's packaged version of Mailman is not well regarded in the community exactly because of its deviations from the standard Mailman package; there are also resources at the link above to help you migrate away from the Apple-packaged version if you wish. Hope that helps!